# Can I store armored trucks in my garage to loot them repeatedly?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In Grand Theft Auto V, making money is difficult, but one way that I've found to make money is to steal armored trucks. Now, I have an idea but I have yet to test it out:

In one part of the game, Michael can buy a 4-car parking garage close to the downtown district. My question is, if I buy that garage, steal 4 armored trucks, and save them in the garage, will I receive money from the trucks each and every time I retrieve them from the garage? Could I use this trick to earn tons of money?

Comment: No, but I like the way you think

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot store armoured trucks in any garage, maybe through some sort of glitch, but there would be no cash outcome, as the games spawns the briefcase of cash before the truck.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the truck in Michael's garage at his house, but I don't know about the money part.

Answer (score -1):

You can store Amoured trucks in hangar I think because it says that vehicles that can’t go in the garage go there, like the crusader.